# Remove any entry from specific row

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am trying to remove the entries from row number 9. Anything there should become null.

My ideas:

1. delete entire row and add a new one afterwards --> I am unable to add a new row somehow. If that's possible I don't know how to add it a position/row number 9 again.
2. Replace anything with null --> I am unable to find a solution for that.

Are there any other ideas? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Table.ReplaceRows` method:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table25"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,
        List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_, Int64.Type})),
    
    //create a record of nulls for each column
    replaceList= Record.FromList(
                    List.Repeat({null},Table.ColumnCount(#"Changed Type")), 
                    Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type")),

    //Replace the row or rows at Offset with the new list
    nullTheRow = Table.ReplaceRows(#"Changed Type",6,1, {replaceList})
  
in
    nullTheRow
```

**Source**
[image]

**replaceList**
[image]

**Results**
[image]

Comment: thanks! adjusted my M-Code accordingly and it works as intended

Answer (score 0):

You could transpose the table and add a column containing only null values. Here is an example using the following sample table:

[image: table_sample]

Here is the M code:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45Wci/KLy0wVNJRMgXikMqCVBDb0EgpVgcqZwTkWyLLmUPkfBQck5PzS/NKioGCQOSTmJSak5qCIgo3xATIM4caAjLQ0FQpNhYA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Account Group" = _t, Value1 = _t, #"Account Type" = _t, Value2 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Account Group", type text}, {"Value1", Int64.Type}, {"Account Type", type text}, {"Value2", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Demoted Headers" = Table.DemoteHeaders(#"Changed Type"),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Demoted Headers"),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Transposed Table", "Custom", each null),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Custom", "Column4"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{"Column4"}),
    #"Transposed Table1" = Table.Transpose(#"Removed Columns"),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table1", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Account Group", type text}, {"Value1", Int64.Type}, {"Account Type", type text}, {"Value2", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

And here is the result:

[image: null_row]